# Is it safe to set rejectUnauthorized to false when using Heroku's Postgres database?

Tags: tls, http, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to put some fields in a Postgres database hosted on a Heroku app and it keeps returning this error:

```
Error: self signed certificate
code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
```

I have tried adding a key, certificate, and CA bundle but to no avail

Many StackOverflow questions with the same error say to set the variable `rejectUnauthorized` to `false` when making the http server. My question is how safe is this with a Postgres database on Heroku and would it pose any threat to the security of the database?

If the information helps I am using a node.js script to send the query to the database.

Comment: Where are you getting this error - on the Postgres server or the client application? How safe is it do disable certification validation depends on your environment and threats faced. If it is a production environment, then DO NOT.

Comment: It's on the server side - from Heroku's logs

Comment: And it will be production so yeah, I'll try to look for other ways around it. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Yep, please do not disable certificate validation in production. Have you tried using the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS_FILE variable on nodejs side? https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file . Save the postgres server certificate file on the nodejs server and set that env variable.

Comment: Would I just set that as an environment variable with the path to the certificate?

Comment: Yes. You should first download the postgres certificate to the nodejs server and then sent the path of the environment variable to that file, and restart the nodejs app.

Comment: Hmm...it isn't working. Same error as always

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku [does not support](https://help.heroku.com/3DELT3RK/why-can-t-my-third-party-utility-connect-to-heroku-postgres-with-ssl) client-side certificate validation to its Postgres databases unless you are using Private Spaces or Shield:

> Unless you're using a Private or Shield Heroku Postgres database, Heroku Postgres does not currently support verifiable certificates.

My understanding is that in this case, the best you can do is:

- Your connection is encrypted and you are protected from eavesdropping
- Not protected against Man-In-The-Middle (MITM) attacks

```
ssl: {
  sslmode: 'require',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
}
```

This is the highest level without certificate validation, according to the table [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html):

[image]